# Why didn't the Judas tree poison kill River too?

Tags: doctor-who, river-song

In Let's Kill Hitler,

> Melody/River gives a kiss to The Doctor with the Judas tree poison on her lips, attempting to kill the doctor.

If she had the same poison on her lips, and after the blow kiss on her hands too, why didn't it affect her as well?
Was it because she was still regenerating, or is there another reason?

Comment: Possibly she had inured herself to its effects through mithridatism?

Comment: Would you believe...[plastic lips](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0587532)?

Comment: @Thunderforge Better?

Comment: @Tuuli id replace it in the question as well

Comment: @Areeb Well, it's marked as a spoiler, so I don't see why..

Comment: @Tuuli it wasn't when I commented

Comment: Because the poison of the Judas tree only works on males. Yes, I made that up.

Comment: Perhaps it's only toxic to Gallifreyan Time Lords.  Is there any reason to suspect that it's toxic to humans, or human-derived Time Ladies, or anything at all that wasn't born and bred of Gallifreyan stock?

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan River still had Time Lord DNA, so I believe it would've had some sort of affect. But like I said earlier in another comment, I think I answered my own question here already. Later in that same episode we see the nazis shooting River, and she survived because she was still regenerating, so I think the same goes for that poison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I finally worked it out.

> So Melody/River applies the poison on her lips and gives the Doctor a lethal kiss. Then she jumps out of the window after sending a blowkiss (so now she has poison on her hand as well as her lips). Then she walks into some nazis, and provoke them so that they shoot her, and because she is still regenerating some regeneration energy bursts out *repairing all the damage*. So that's when the poisoning gets cured.

The poison itself couldn't trigger the regeneration, that's why the Doctor was dying. But Melody/River was already regenerating. That enabled her to use the Judas tree poison, because she just needed to get hurt again to trigger the ongoing regeneration that cured her.

Comment: This would also explain why she waited until regenerating from Mels before starting to attack the Doctor, which I was wondering just the other day.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe she took the antidote somehow. First i thought she took the antidote before jumping the window, while she send the air kiss. But keeping a chemical substance on your palm is is very difficult. Though, not impossible.

Comment: According to Amelia-as-voice-interface, ["there is no cure."](https://youtu.be/EhMdOuN6h6o?t=1m5s)

Comment: I believe I've already answered my own question here, and the key is in her regeneration. The Doctor couldn't regenerate after he was poisoned, but because Rivers regeneration was just happened and still going on, that's why she didn't die. I just wanted to make sure :)